# Dual formula in first-order. A common syntactical proof?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

The statement:

> If $\mathscr B$ is a formula without conditionals and $\mathscr B^*$ is obtained by exchanging quantifiers and exchanging $\land$, $\lor$ connectives, then $\vdash \mathscr B$ if and only if $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^*$.

I have been bashing my head with the syntactical proof of this theorem. On this site there is a question about it, but the answerer proves the trivial case of conjunction only. The usual approach is with induction. The base case is easy: we don't have $\vdash P$ and we don't have $\vdash \neg P$, so it holds. As for the inductive step; the cases of conjunction and universal quantifier are easy. But the existential quantifier and disjunction cases are not so obvious! Indeed, if we have $\mathscr B$ to be $(\exists x) \mathscr C$, assuming $\vdash \mathscr B$, what is anything we can do? We could get rid of the quantifier, if we knew $x$ is not free in $\mathscr C$, but it is not the case... assuming not $\vdash (\exists x) \neg \mathscr C^*$ for a contradictory argument does not point to anything interesting.

So I constructed some lemmas that seem to prove the statement. It uses the intuitive idea that the negated dual with negated atomics is actually the same as the original formula.

**Lemma 1.** If $\mathscr B$ is a formula without conditionals, $\mathscr B^*$ is its dual, and $\mathscr B'$ denotes the variant of $\mathscr B$ with a negation sign put before each atomic formula, then $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr B'$, so that $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^*$ if and only if $\vdash \mathscr B'$.

**Proof.** If $\mathscr B$ is an atomic $P$, then its dual is $P$ and its negation is $\neg P$, which is $\mathscr B'$. So it's trivial to see $\vdash \neg P \leftrightarrow \neg P$. Assume the claim holds for $r < q$ connectives and quantifiers.

Case 1. $\mathscr B$ is $(\forall x) \mathscr C$. The negated dual is $\neg (\exists x) \mathscr C^*$. By definition, it's $\neg \neg (\forall x) \neg \mathscr C^*$, which is equivalent to $(\forall x) \neg \mathscr C^*$. Have $\vdash \neg \mathscr C^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C'$, so $\vdash (\forall x) \neg \mathscr C^* \leftrightarrow (\forall x) \mathscr C'$, so $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr B'$.

Case 2. $\mathscr B$ is $(\exists x) \mathscr C$. The negated dual is $\neg (\forall x) \mathscr C^*$, which is equivalent to $(\exists x) \neg \mathscr C^*$. Have $\vdash \neg \mathscr C^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C'$, so $(\exists x) \neg \mathscr C^* \leftrightarrow (\exists x) \mathscr C'$, so $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr B'$.

Case 3. $\mathscr B$ is $\mathscr C_1 \land \mathscr C_2$. The negated dual is $\neg (\mathscr C_1^* \lor \mathscr C_2^*)$, which is equivalent to $\neg \mathscr C_1^* \land \neg \mathscr C_2^*$. Have $\vdash \neg \mathscr C_1^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C_1'$ and $\vdash \neg \mathscr C_2^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C_2'$, from which $\vdash \neg \mathscr C_1^* \land \neg \mathscr C_2^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C_1' \land \mathscr C_2'$ and therefore $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr B'$.

Case 4. $\mathscr B$ is $\mathscr C_1 \lor \mathscr C_2$. The negated dual is $\neg (\mathscr C_1^* \land \mathscr C_2^*)$, which is equivalent to $\neg \mathscr C_1^* \lor \neg \mathscr C_2^*$. Have $\vdash \neg \mathscr C_1^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C_1'$ and $\vdash \neg \mathscr C_2^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C_2'$. Again $\vdash \neg \mathscr C_1^* \lor \neg \mathscr C_2^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C_1' \lor \mathscr C_2'$, which is $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr B'$.

Case 5. $\mathscr B$ is $\neg \mathscr C$. The negated dual is $\neg \neg \mathscr C^*$. Have $\vdash \neg \mathscr C^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr C'$, which is to say $\vdash \neg \neg \mathscr C^* \leftrightarrow \neg \mathscr C'$, so $\vdash \neg \mathscr B^* \leftrightarrow \mathscr B'$.

**Lemma 2.** If $\mathscr B'$ denotes a variant of $\mathscr B$ with a negation sign placed before each atomic formula, then $\vdash \mathscr B$ if and only if $\vdash \mathscr B'$.

**Proof.** We assume that $\mathscr B$ has atomics. Assume $\vdash \mathscr B$. In the proof $\mathscr D_1,\dots,\mathscr D_n$ of $\mathscr B$, each $\mathscr D_i$ is either an axiom, or obtained with MP or Gen. Put a negation sign before each atomic formula, now we obtain a proof of $\vdash \mathscr B'$. Assume $\vdash \mathscr B'$. In the proof of this formula, erase a negation sign from each occurrence of an atomic.

**NOTE:** I am working with Mendelson's Introduction to Logic. He does not introduce the completeness theorem at this point, so the proof must be syntactial. The theory I use is the basic predicate calculus without equality notion.

**Questions:**

- These two lemmas seem to prove the statement. Are the lemmas correct, and do they prove the statement about duals in the question?
- If my findings are not correct, could you point me to a correct direction and provide with information what could I do with the disjunction and existential quantifier cases? These seem hopeless to me.
- I am a bit suspicious of rigorousness of the proof of Lemma 2. Could it be improved?